# can I bind to specific interface for different samba shares?

Tags: ubuntu, samba

for example, something similar than this:

```
[share-with-vms]
interfaces = 192.168.100.1/24 virbr0
path = /samba-shared/for-local-vms
[share-with-peer]
interfaces = 10.200.0.10/24 eno2
path = /samba-shared/for-peers
```

But the interfaces key seems does not work outside global section.

Maybe I can use `hosts allow` instead? where can I find which key is in which scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation (`man smb.conf`) contains a bracketed letter after each directive:

- `(G)` indicates a global parameter, i.e. it can exist only in the global section
- `(S)` indications section parameter. These can also appear in the global section where they will set a default that can be later overridden in the individual sections

The documentation for `hosts allow` declares it as `hosts allow (S)` so this directive can be used per section.

> This parameter is a comma, space, or tab delimited set of hosts which are permitted to access a service [...]

> You can specify the hosts by name or IP number. For example, you could restrict access to only the hosts on a Class C subnet with something like `allow hosts = 150.203.5.`. The full syntax of the list is described in the man page `hosts_access(5)` [...]

> You can also specify hosts by network/netmask pairs [...]

and it goes on to give specific examples using IP addresses and address/subnet ranges.

Your example would probably work if written like this,

```
[share-with-vms]
        hosts allow = 192.168.100.0/24
        path = /samba-shared/for-local-vms

[share-with-peer]
        hosts allow = 10.200.0.10
        path = /samba-shared/for-peers
```